# If the closed unit ball of Banach space has at least one extreme point, must the Banach space the be a dual space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convexity, duality, extreme-points

Let $X$ be a Banach space.
By Banach-Alaoglu and Krein-Milman Theorems, one can show that if $X$ is a dual space, then $X$ must have at least one extreme point of the closed unit ball.

I am interested in its converse.
More precisely,

> Question: Let $X$ be a Banach space. 
>   If the closed unit ball of $X$ has at least one extreme point, must $X$ be a dual space?

I feel that the statement above is negative. 
However, I could not produce a counterexample.

In fact, the only Banach spaces which I know that  are not dual spaces are $c_0$ and $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ (the latter set is the collection of all real-valued continuous function vanishing at infinity) because both sets have no extreme point.

Comment: When you say that "$X$ has at least one extreme point" do you mean that the *closed unit ball* of $X$ has at least on extreme point?

Comment: I have added the tag ([tag:extreme-points]), since it seems to me a good fit to the question. There exists also ([tag:krein-milman-theorem]) tag, but that one would probably be a stretch.

Comment: This post on Mathematics site seems to be about the same question: [Krein-Milman and dual spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2518559).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I mean the closed unit ball of $X.$

Comment: @TarasBanakh: There *are* infinite compact $K$ for which $C(K)$ is a dual space: these are precisely the hyperstonean $K$, e.g., $\beta\mathbb{N}$. (On the other hand there are non-dual $C(K)$ for which the unit ball is the norm-closed convex hull of its extreme points, e.g. $\alpha\mathbb{N}$. These are precisely the totally disconected $K$.)

Comment: @Idonknow: The question is already answered extensively, but let me add one quick example. The identity of any unital $C^*$-algebra is an extreme point of its closed unit ball, but, of course, not all unital $C^*$-algebras are von Neumann algebras (=$C^*$-algebras with Banach space predual).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every separable Banach space $X$ can be equivalently renormed so that every point in the unit sphere is an extreme point: Take an injective bounded linear operator $T$ from $X$ into $\ell_2$ and use $|x| := \|x\|_X + \|Tx\|_2$.  Of course, there are many separable Banach spaces that are not isomorphic to a separable conjugate space, including (as Dirk pointed out) those that fail the Radon Nikodym property.

Answer (score 8):

No. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and set $Z=X\oplus Y$, with $\||(x,y)|\|:=\|x\|+\|y\|$. Assume that $x$ is a extreme point of $X$ with $\|x\|=1$. Then $(x,0)$ becomes an extreme point of $Z$; indeed, if 
$$(x,0)=\frac12(a,y)+\frac12(b,z)$$
for $(a,y),(b,z)$ in the unit ball of $Z$, we then have $a=x=b$, since $x$ is an extreme point, but then $1=\|x\|=\|a\|\leq\||(a,y)|\|\leq 1$, so $y=0$, and analogously, $z=0$.

So, $L^2(\mathbb R)\oplus L^1(\mathbb R)$, is not a dual space, but its unit ball has extreme points.

Comment: How can we prove that $L^2(\mathbb R)\oplus L^1(\mathbb R)$ is not a dual space?

Comment: @Idonknow This is because, $X\oplus Y$ is dual iff both $X$ and $Y$ are dual.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan: I am not absolutely positive about your previous comment: Write $C[0,1]^*$ as $L_1[0,1] \oplus_1 Y$ with $Y=$ singular measures w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. So a dual can have a non-dual $\ell_1$-direct summand. My argument: If $L_2\oplus L_1$ were a dual, it would, being separable, have the RNP, and hence $L_1$ would have the RNP, which it doesn't.

Comment: @DirkWerner Thanks for the comment, you are right!